# why is my simple tictactoe app crashing immediately when launched on android?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I can't get my app to work on Android.

I developed a simple tictactoe app using python and kivy. when I run the app using the command prompt on the pc it works just fine but when I use builozer version 0.37 to build the apk and install it on my phone it just crashes immediately. I have tried to build a 'hello world' app before and it worked just fine. so I am really confused as to what might be the issue. I am using kivy version 1.10.1. I ran the app on a Galaxy S7(I don't know if that would help or not). I apologize in advance for my sloppy code, I am still new to app development and this is my first full app. Note that I only programmed with python 3 before, when I tried to specify python 3 in the spec file the building process failed, so I changed it to hostpython 2(maybe this is the thing that is causing the issue)

I would highly appreciate any help provided.

this is my python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import (Line, Ellipse, Rectangle)
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random

# I set a global variable because I don't know how to change another screen/class variable using the first screen

aioption = BooleanProperty(False)

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self):
    super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
    self.set_aioption()

    def set_aioption(self):
    button = self.ids.ai_button
    button.bind(on_press = self.option_true)

    def option_true(self, *args):
    global aioption
    aioption = True
    # for debugging porpuses
    print('success in changing global variable')

class WinnerPopup(Popup):
    pass


class GameScreen(Screen):
    #defining all variables we need

    global aioption
    turn = 1
    checking_threshold = 0
    isX = BooleanProperty(False)
    isO = BooleanProperty(False)
    result = StringProperty('')
    # this checks if a button is used or not
    isavail = BooleanProperty(True)
    haswon = BooleanProperty(False)

    def drawX(self, button):
        # creates the X sign
        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(0,0,0.5,1)
            Line(points = [button.x, button.y, button.x+button.width, button.y+button.height], width = 0.03*button.width)
            Line(points = [button.x+button.width, button.y, button.x, button.y+button.height], width = 0.03*button.width)

    def drawO(self, button):
        #draws the O sign
        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(0.5,0,0,1)
            Line(width = 0.03*button.width, circle = (button.center_x, button.center_y, min(button.width, button.height)
                / 2))

    def winning(self, result):

    #handles popup at the end

    box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
    play_btn = Button(text= 'play again', font_size = '20sp')
    exit_btn = Button(text = 'exit', font_size = '20sp')
    winner_label = Label(text= result,
                         font_size= '30sp')
    wp = WinnerPopup(title = 'Winner',
                     id = 'mypopup'
                     , size_hint_y = None, size_hint_x= None
                     , size=(0.5*self.width, 0.5*self.height),
                     auto_dismiss = False)

    play_btn.bind(on_press = self.reset_game)
    play_btn.bind(on_press = self.change_welcome)
    play_btn.bind(on_press = wp.dismiss)
    exit_btn.bind(on_press = self.exit_app)
    wp.add_widget(box)
    box.add_widget(winner_label)
    box.add_widget(play_btn)
    box.add_widget(exit_btn)

    wp.open()

    def exit_app(self, *args):
    App.get_running_app().stop()
    Window.close()

    def change_welcome(self, *args):
    self.manager.current = 'welcomescreen'

    def check_winner(self):
    b1 = self.ids.button1
    b2 = self.ids.button2
    b3 = self.ids.button3
    b4 = self.ids.button4
    b5 = self.ids.button5
    b6 = self.ids.button6
    b7 = self.ids.button7
    b8 = self.ids.button8
    b9 = self.ids.button9

    #checks for winning conditions

    if ((b1.isX == True and b2.isX == True and b3.isX == True)
    or (b1.isX == True and b4.isX == True and b7.isX == True)
    or (b1.isX == True and b5.isX == True and b9.isX == True)
    or (b2.isX == True and b5.isX == True and b8.isX == True)
    or (b3.isX == True and b6.isX == True and b9.isX == True)
    or (b4.isX == True and b5.isX == True and b6.isX == True)
    or (b7.isX == True and b8.isX == True and b9.isX == True)
    or (b3.isX == True and b5.isX == True and b7.isX == True)):

        self.haswon = True
        self.result = "X's won"
        self.winning(self.result)

    elif ((b1.isO == True and b2.isO == True and b3.isO == True)
    or (b1.isO == True and b4.isO == True and b7.isO == True)
    or (b1.isO == True and b5.isO == True and b9.isO == True)
    or (b2.isO == True and b5.isO == True and b8.isO == True)
    or (b3.isO == True and b6.isO == True and b9.isO == True)
    or (b4.isO == True and b5.isO == True and b6.isO == True)
    or (b7.isO == True and b8.isO == True and b9.isO == True)
    or (b3.isO == True and b5.isO == True and b7.isO == True)):

        self.haswon = True
        self.result = "O's won"
        self.winning(self.result)

    elif self.checking_threshold >= 8:

        self.result = 'it is a draw'
        self.winning(self.result)

    def reset_game(self, *args):
    self.turn = 1
    self.checking_threshold = 0
    self.result = ''
    self.haswon = False
    global aioption
    aioption = False
    for i in range(1,10):
        self.ids[f'button{i}'].isX = False
        self.ids[f'button{i}'].isO = False
        self.ids[f'button{i}'].isavail = True

    self.canvas.after.clear()

    #fake AI, just chooses a random postition
    def ai_engine(self, *args):
    label = self.ids.game_label
    flag = False
    while flag == False and self.turn % 2 == 0:        
        random_int = random.randint(1, 9)
        button = self.ids[f'button{random_int}']

        if button.isavail == True:
            button.isO = True
            label.text = "it's X's turn"
            label.color = [0,0,0.5,1]
            self.drawO(button)
            flag = True
            self.turn += 1
            button.isavail = False
            self.checking_threshold += 1


    # condition that changes the game mode                
    def sign(self, button):
    if aioption == True:
        label = self.ids.game_label
        #makes sure match cant go on when game is over
        if self.haswon != True:
            if button.isavail == True:
                if self.turn % 2 != 0:
                    self.drawX(button)
                    label.text = "it's AI's turn"
                    label.color = [0.5,0,0,1]
                    button.isX = True
                    self.turn += 1
                    button.isavail = False
                    self.checking_threshold += 1
                    self.ai_engine()

                if self.checking_threshold >= 3:
                    self.check_winner()



            else: 
                print('the button is not available')
    else:
        label = self.ids.game_label
        if self.haswon != True:
            if button.isavail == True:
                if self.turn % 2 != 0:
                    self.drawX(button)
                    label.text = "it's O's turn"
                    label.color = [0.5,0,0,1]
                    button.isX = True
                else:
                    button.isO = True
                    label.text = "it's X's turn"
                    label.color = [0,0,0.5,1]
                    self.drawO(button)

                if self.checking_threshold >= 4:
                    self.check_winner()

                button.isavail = False
                self.turn += 1
                self.checking_threshold += 1


            else: 
                print('the button is not available')


class TicTacToe2App(App):
    def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen())
    sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name = 'gamescreen'))
    return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TicTacToe2App().run()
```

this is my kv file:

```
<Button>:
    isX: False
    isO: False
    isavail: True


<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcomescreen'
    BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size:root.width, 0.4*root.height

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,0.5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            size_hint: None, None
            text: 'Welcome to TicTacToe'
            center: self.parent.center
            font_size: '50sp'
            size: self.texture_size
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            center: self.parent.center
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                id: human_button
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 0.2*root.width, 0.1*root.height
                text: '1 vs 1'
                font_size: '20sp'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'gamescreen'
            Button:
                id: ai_button
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 0.2*root.width, 0.1*root.height
                text: '1 vs Bot'
                font_size: '20sp'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'gamescreen'
                on_press: root.aioption = True
<GameScreen>:
    name: 'gamescreen'
    BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        id: myfloat
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 0.2*root.height
        Label:
            id: game_label
            center: self.parent.center
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 0.8*root.width
            color: 0,0,1,0.85
            text: "X's turn"
            font_size: '35sp'

    GridLayout:
        id: mygrid
        cols: 3
        rows: 3
        padding: 0.05*root.width
        spacing: 0.02*root.width
        Button:
            id: button1
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,0.8
                Rectangle:
                    pos: (self.width + self.x), (root.y+0.025*root.width)
                    size: (0.02*root.width), (mygrid.height-0.05*root.width)
            on_press: root.sign(self)
        Button:
            id: button2
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,0.8
                Rectangle:
                    pos: (self.width + self.x), (root.y+0.025*root.width)
                    size: (0.02*root.width), (mygrid.height-0.05*root.width)
            on_press: root.sign(self)
        Button:
            id: button3
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,1,1
        Button:
            id: button4
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,0.8
                Rectangle:
                    pos: (root.x + 0.025*root.width) , (self.y + self.height)
                    size: (mygrid.width - 0.05*root.width) , (0.02*root.width)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: (root.x + 0.025*root.width) , (self.y - 0.02*root.width)
                    size: (mygrid.width - 0.05*root.width) , (0.02*root.width)
        Button:
            id: button5
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Button:
            id: button6
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Button:
            id: button7 
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Button:
            id: button8
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Button:
            id: button9
            background_color: 0,0,0,0

            on_press: root.sign(self)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
```

this is my buildozer spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Tic Tac Toe

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.mydomain

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,kv

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = hostpython2,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1
#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = /home/kivy/Downloads/android-ndk-r13b/

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
build_dir = /build/myapp

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

this is the link to the adb logcat output( i filtered output using this statement `adb logcat | findstr com.example.package`):

https://github.com/theyoungthunder/app-logcat-output/blob/master/logcat%20output.txt

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: thanks for your comment. I did add a link to a text file containing the output.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3

Your app runs fine on Acer tablet using Android version 5.0.1. The apk file was builded using Buildozer 0.39, Python 3, Kivy 1.10.1, and Cython 0.28.6, on Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

## Python 2

Your app failed to run with Python 2. The failure was due to Python 3 string format used.

[image: Python2 - SyntaxError]

## Solution

### Upgrade Buildozer

```
pip install --upgrade buildozer
```

### buildozer.spec

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy
```

### Android on Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cython==0.28.6
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential ccache git libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 python2.7 python2.7-dev openjdk-8-jdk unzip zlib1g-dev zlib1g:i386
```

### Android on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit)

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cython==0.21
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential ccache git libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 python2.7 python2.7-dev openjdk-8-jdk unzip zlib1g-dev zlib1g:i386
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I almost lost hope. one more thing, can you please use another code for the python 2 syntax error please

Comment: also, my ubuntu version is 17.04, which set of commands should I use.

Comment: I have replaced `f'...'` with `'button' + str(i)`. The apk file for Python 2 runs fine on Acer tablet. Use the set of commands for 18.04.